# Python Error Handling Retry Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Im trying to build a definition that does error checking for my definitions. What is the proper way to structure this code for error handling?

I want the script to run a specified definition, if it fails, retry a number of times, then kill it if it times out.

```
import time

def open_file():
    open('testfile.py')

def run_def(definition):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        try:
            definition
            str_error = None
        except Exception as str_error:
            pass
            if str_error:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(str_error)
            else:
                break
                print('kill script')

run_def(open_file())
```

I get an error when I try passing the definition into the error check definition. But the script works if I dont put the error checker into a separate definition.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testfile.py'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Your `open_file` function returns `None`. So doing `run_def(open_file())` calls `run_def` with an arg of `None`. And so `definition` in the `try` block won't ever raise an exception.

Comment: Are you perchance running run_def and open_file in different folders? Try using an absolute path to the file. Also, for what you are doing - try looking at decorators  https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: Im not really opening a file, Im just trying to create a generic error

Comment: Try to remove call on parameter `run_def(open_file)` then in function do `definition()`. Normally error will be catched.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, but I would think run_def should just check the condition of definition and return, you can have a loop that calls it x number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to catch exception, your call function should be placed in your `try / except` block.

Like this:

```
import time

def open_file():
    open('testfile.py')

def run_def(definition):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        try:
            definition()
        except Exception as str_error:
            if str_error:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(str_error)
            else:
                break
                print('kill script')

run_def(open_file)
```

You don't need to pass after `except`.

And you don't need to initialize `str_error` variable before. (Unless you use it before...)